# Return result of SELECT to another procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have problem with "returning" one procedure result to another procedure.

Description:

For example we have complex SELECT with parameters putted in one procedure.

```
USE [myDB]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure1 @today date
AS


SELECT * FROM complex_query
```

now it's returning a lot of columns and numbers of columns and rows depends on **@today** value.

No I want to use result of **Procedure1** in **Procedure2**

```
USE [myDB]
GO

DECLARE @cntMonth INT = 0;

WHILE @cntMonth < 12  
BEGIN
  SELECT x,y,z FROM result_of_Procedure1
  SET @cntMonth = @cntMonth + 1;
END;
```

why I want it like that?
It's because the software I'm working on is connecting to DB, run procedure and get the result to frontend. So I have to code all the way in SQL.
So assuming software is doing one-time connection I don't want to got through *Procedure1* every time **WHILE** statement is executed. How can I store the effect of Procedure1 to use it through Procedure2 while loop and prevent multiple runs of Procedure1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE #TempResults
( 
  -- put definition of columns returned from your Procedure1 SP here
)

INSERT INTO #TempResults
EXEC Procedure1

-- now you have your result from Procedure1 in #TempResults
-- use it whatever way you want
SELECT * FROM #TempResults

-- finally drop the temp table when no longer needed
DROP TABLE #TempResults
```

Comment: ok, and if second user will start this procedure in same time will there be a problem with temp table #TempResults already existing?

Comment: No, each temp table (created with `#` prefix) is unique to a session/connection. So two users won't mess up with each other.